# How to save data from input field in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I have problem - I need to put data from form into database...With Backbone usage!
How to do that?
What i need to write in my scrips and HTMLs?
My collection is:

```
define([
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "jquery"

    ],
    function(_, Backbone, $) {
        return Backbone.Collection.extend({

            url: '/users/all' //route for get ALL users in DB
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just create a method that iterates over your html form each time the user hits submit:

```
store: function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    //select each input, select and textarea within this views $el
    _.each(this.$('input, select, textarea'), function(input)
    {
        //you input name attribute to set the correct model attribute.
        this.model.set(input.name, input.value);
    }, this);

    //new model attributes from the form are now available and ready to be synced
    //with the server.
    console.log(this.model.toJSON());
}
```

Check this [**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kyleNeedham/B6gEf/).